# when creating JSON, how to avoid getting same data twice into JSON

Tags: java, json

I need some advice. I´ve built a tool that does image operations for uploaded pictures and saves the results. Each time an operation is done, it creates an entry in a JSON file in its folder. 
So if there is no JSON it creates a new one and if there is a JSON it appends the information. The problem is, if someone accidentally adds an image that already had been added, the json appends the information again.

Its too much code to post here, but I would be thankful if someone has some advice on how to compare the files before appending or something else.

Comment: hash the file contents, compare the hashed string?

Comment: I didnt explain properly. Each json is the result of more than one operation:

one operation to add the image properties and other operations to add scale information from a json schema. So I think the comparing the hashed string wont work, right?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*"Its too much code to post here"*, so I am going just to lay down the approach fundamentals :) .

An in memory solution would work if you never use the same folder again after exiting the application. If you count duplicates by a property like picture name, then you can go for a simple solution like a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String,Boolean> hashMapImages = ...
String newImageName = ...
if (! hashMapImages.containsKey(newImageName)){
      hashMapImages.put(newImageName,true);
      //... append to JSON
}
```

If you actually want distinct pictures in content you have to design a hash function for your images. As an example you could use a hash function which sums pixel values every 256 pixels away. For random images it is enough to get a distinctive hash value.

```
int pos = 0;
long hashsum;
while (pos< image.length){
     hashsum += image[pos];
     pos += 256;
}
long hashKey = hashsum % 65536; //for a 16 bit key
```

If you plan to reuse same folder again construct an additional JSON file which contains just the key values (whichever key you choose to use). Parse this JSON file and check if you have the image, before appending.

```
HashMap<String,Boolean> hashMapImages = loadFromJSONContentFolder();
    String key = getKey()
    if (! hashMapImages.containsKey(key)){
          hashMapImages.put(key,true);
          //... append to JSON
    }
```